# get Process ID via JMX

Tags: java, linux, jmx

I am adding following JVM parameters to connect the application via JMX.
After connected the application via jconsole over JMX, is there a menu that shows me the running application PID?

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5592 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Linux Redhat 6.2
java JDK 1.6

Comment: I do not think so because there is no discussion about JMX tools such as jconsole tool.  I have found a solution.

Comment: Any JMX tools such as jconsole or VisualVM can obtain this MXBean.  I suggest you use VisualVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jps

```
$ jps -lm
3457 com.intellij.idea.Main
3524 org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer
12059 org.netbeans.Main --userdir /home/peter/.visualvm/7u14 --cachedir /home/peter/.cache/visualvm/7u14 --branding visualvm
12162 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lm
```

VisualVM is a replacement for jconsole.

[image]

Comment: I know JPS but I have not used "-lm" option. It is really great. I have learned an other way easier than jmx tool one.

Comment: @mmc18 I usually use `jps -lvm` but the output was too long to put in the answer. ;)

Comment: how about if there are multiple running same applications. for that case "lvm" directly addresses the running application

Comment: @mmc18 you can add a property to the command line just so you can tell one from another.

Answer (score 5):

I have tracked the java.lang->RunTime->Name
I think format of Name Attribute starts with PID
So running applications IP is 5741
[image]

Comment: You can also find out the name of the host that JVM runs on from that attribute, a very elegant solution IMHO.